# Need help for imagemagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

You need to write a python script that takes the files ( images + logo) from a given directory,
and outputs the resulting ppt file in the same directory.

Comment: `@Jitender Patel`  Do you tried any sample code? If you tried please post, then I will look your code.

Comment: No. I don't know how to write.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.